# Kendo Grid + Pager: Cannot call method 'value' of kendoDropDownList before it is initialized

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, pager

I made a SPA, and I replace the #content after every menu element click.
First time when I load a grid it's work correctly. After when I click to the menu element I get this error message: Cannot call method 'value' of kendoDropDownList before it is initialized.
If I don't use pager it's work correctly.
Can somebody help me?

Here is the code:

```
var obuDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function(data) {
                return api_url_v1+"obus/user/"+$.cookie('user')+"?ssid="+$.cookie('ssid');
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(response,type) {
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10
});

webcontrol.route("/obus", function() {
    $("#content").html(obus({}));
    $("#obus").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: obuDS,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "name",        title: "Name",      width: 50, template: "<a href=\"\\#/obu/#:obu#/0\">#:name#</a>" },
            { field: "obu",         title: "OBU",   width: 70},
            { field: "country",     title: "Country",       width: 30 },
            { field: "eurocode",    title: "EURO",          width: 30 }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: I found the solution: if you use as pageable: true, it's work correctly.

Comment: Could you please explain what you did? It's not clear to me how you changed your code. Also, add it as an answer, please.

Comment: The problem is that there is no property called `pageSizes` on the `pageable` object. Also, there is no property named `complete` in the transport. Please read the Kendo documentation - [link](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid).

Comment: Actually there is a property named `pageSizes` in `pageable` object. However this property makes this error for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and yes there is a fix for it, basically you just need to destroy the grid before your redirect...

The best way to tackle this is by using "resolve" in $routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/' + nPageData.id, {
                    controller: nPageData.id + "Controller",
                    template: vm.getPageHTML(nPageData),
                    resolve:{
                        "kendogridfix":function($location){
                            angular.element("[kendo-grid]").each(function(idx,kGrid){
                                var dataObj=angular.element(kGrid).data();
                                for(mData in dataObj)
                                {
                                    if(angular.isObject(dataObj[mData]))
                                    {
                                        if("destroy" in dataObj[mData])
                                        {
                                            dataObj[mData].destroy();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps...